# How to convert output string to Json and check field item in python?

Tags: python, json, pandas, azureservicebus

I'm a beginner at Python. I received a message from the Azure service bus like the below screenshot and below code.

[image]

The code for receiving messages from the Service bus is:

```
import logging
import json

import azure.functions as func


def main(message: func.ServiceBusMessage):

    message_content_type = message.content_type
    message_body = message.get_body().decode("utf-8")
    logging.info(message_body)
    message = "MSG Received"
    logging.info(message)
```

Now, I want to convert `message_body` from string to JSON and after that, I check the below condition:

```
If error = null and MSG_TYPE_TAG != Null
```

How can I run this scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert string to JSON

```
message_body = json.loads(message_body)
```

Now, check the condition

```
if message_body['error'] == {} and message_body['MSG_TYPE_TAG'] != '':
    # write your logic here
```

**Code**

```
import json

message_body = json.loads(message_body)

if message_body['error'] == {} and message_body['MSG_TYPE_TAG'] != '':
    # write your logic here
```